# Python - error using variables outside function

Tags: python, function

I have two Python files: ***checkprice.py*** and ***test2.py***.
 The second one contains the function `getItemInfo()` which basically gets the info of an item from a website (in particular the price, called `item_price_edited_eur`). I need to use the price in the ***checkprice.py*** file so I've set the `item_price_edited_eur` variable as the return of the `getItemInfo()` function and I assigned the value of the variable `item_price_edited_eur` to the function (in this sense: `item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()`). In this way I shoud be able to use the variable outside the function but it doesn't work, I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkprice.py", line 25, in <module>
    item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()
TypeError: getItemInfo() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'item_url', 'item_name_xpath', 'item_game_xpath', 'item_price_xpath', and 'item_quantity_sold_xpath'`

How can I fix this?

---

This is ***the test2.py*** file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def getItemInfo(item_url,item_name_xpath,item_game_xpath,item_price_xpath,item_quantity_sold_xpath):
    #info includes item name, game, quantity sold and price
    from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
    from selenium import webdriver
    path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\\Users\\Emanuele-PC\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe'
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
    browser.get(item_url)
    item_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath(item_name_xpath).text
    item_game = browser.find_element_by_xpath(item_game_xpath).text
    item_price = browser.find_element_by_xpath(item_price_xpath).text
    item_quantity_sold = browser.find_element_by_xpath(item_quantity_sold_xpath).text
    #item_price isn't an integer, it's a string, 'Prezzo iniziale: $' and 'USD' need to be cut with .replace, then converted to int with int()
    #item_price_edited is the int() variable, ready to be used
    item_price_cut1 = item_price.replace('Prezzo iniziale:','')
    item_price_cut2 = item_price_cut1.replace('$','')
    item_price_cut3 = item_price_cut2.replace('USD','')
    item_price_edited_usd = float(item_price_cut3)
    #the value of the price is USD, it needs to be converted to EUR
    c = CurrencyRates()
    #round arrotonda il valore con la virgola a due numeri decimali
    item_price_edited_eur = round(c.convert('USD', 'EUR', item_price_edited_usd),2)
    #print(item_name)
    #print(item_game)
    #print(item_price_edited_eur)
    #print(item_quantity_sold)
    return item_price_edited_eur
```

This one is the ***checkprice.py*** file:

```
import mysql.connector
from test2 import getItemInfo
from time import gmtime, strftime

#getItemInfo requires as inputs(item_url,item_name_xpath,item_price_xpath,item_quantity_sold_xpath)

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='user1',password='pass1',db='mm')
cursor = conn.cursor()
select_query = """SELECT * FROM items_basic_info"""
cursor.execute(select_query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    #row[0] is id
    #row[1] is item_name
    #row[2] is item_name_xpath
    #row[3] is item_game
    #row[4] is item_game_xpath
    #row[5] is item_price_xpath
    #row[6] is item_url
    #row[7] is item_quantity_sold_xpath
    getItemInfo(row[6],row[2],row[4],row[5],row[7])
    date_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    #insert_query inserts price of items in items_price
    update_query = """UPDATE items_price SET item_price = %s, last_updated = %s WHERE item_name = %s"""
    item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()   
    cursor.execute(update_query,(item_price_edited_eur, date_time, row[1]))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Check no. of arguments. The error message is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your `getItem()` function in `test2.py` requires 5 arguments.

> def
>   getItemInfo(item_url,item_name_xpath,item_game_xpath,item_price_xpath,item_quantity_sold_xpath):

You are not providing them in the call form `checkprice.py` where you are calling it with no arguments

> item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()

And that is the error that python is throwing, in your call in `checkprice.py` you need to pass all the arguments.

Edit: 
On this line `item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()` you are calling the function again.

what you need to do is change this line `getItemInfo(row[6],row[2],row[4],row[5],row[7])` to `item_price_edited_eur 
 = getItemInfo(row[6],row[2],row[4],row[5],row[7])` and remove the line with `item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo()` this should hopefully get you sorted.

Comment: So basically I should change `getItemInfo(row[6],row[2],row[4],row[5],row[7])` to `item_price_edited_eur = getItemInfo(row[6],row[2],row[4],row[5],row[7])`, right? EDIT Yes this was the change I had to do, thanks for the help.